# How do I save values as new columns using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file, say a1, that contains some values,

```
6  8  8  
10 8  8
5  8  8
```

After taking the average of each column using the following commands,

```
awk '{ total += $1 } END { print total/NR }' a1
awk '{ total += $2 } END { print total/NR }' a1
awk '{ total += $3 } END { print total/NR }' a1
```

I get three values, say avg1 (which is 7 for the average of the first column), avg2 (8), and avg 3 (8). How do I streamline this process using awk so that the values are printed and saved into a new file where the avg1 value is placed in the first column, avg2 in the second column, and avg3 in the third column, so that the file, say b1, looks like this,

```
7 8 8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dynamic solution, it not depends of the number of columns:

```
 awk '{
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[i]+=$i}
 }
 END {
     for (i in a) {printf "%s ", a[i]/NR}
     print ""
}' file
```

### Output

```
 7 8 8
```

Comment: Theoretically, at least, I don't think the order of indexes in `for (i in a)` is guaranteed (_By default, the order in which a ‘for (indx in array)’ loop scans an array is not defined; it is generally based upon the internal implementation of arrays inside awk._, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html)

Comment: The code is almost perfect, unfortunately the output I have been getting is '8 8 7'.

Comment: Can you test another version of awk ? gawk in first, nawk... Please, read comment of @jas upper